# Google Cloud Run with gunicorn/flask - getting intermittent 504s

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I run a Flask application on Cloud Run with gunicorn and worker type gthread. On low level, this API just writes/retrieves entries from Datastore and Pubsub so all operations are light. The traffic is 20,000 requests a day with max QPS 20 requests and average QPS 2

Every few days/weeks, a portion of traffic (25%-50%) gets a 504 response with the following error:

> *The request has been terminated because it has reached the maximum request timeout. To change this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout*

After a few hours, the issue resolves itself (redeploying the app or a new CR instance kicking in solves it instantly). Those 504 requests don't seem to even reach the application. This error does not seem to be linked to any errors in stderr, stdout or increases in QPS. I've set up some advanced logging and cloud profiler but I don't get any useful information. This application ran perfectly fine on App Engine with gunicorn sync worker. The only difference is gunicorn settings. Sync worker worked very slow on CR so I used gthread instead.

Any ideas where to look next?

Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn"]
CMD ["-b", ":8080", "--worker-class", "gthread", "--workers", "5", "--threads", "2", "api.app:app" ]
```

app.py

```
def run(**kwargs):
    app.run(port=8080, debug=False)


app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', resolver=connexion.resolver.RestyResolver('api'))
app.app.config.from_object(Config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

gcloud deploy command:

```
gcloud run deploy ${service_name} \
...
--image=${image} \
--concurrency=80 \
--memory=2Gi \
--cpu=2 
...
```

Comment: What is the timeout currently set to? (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) Any additional details about what the app is doing?

Comment: hey @DustinIngram, I tried setting the timeout to 60s but noticed no difference. So I took it out. 

The app is a notification system. Engineers push status of their ETL jobs for others to query it. On POST, it adds an entry to pubsub and datastore. On GET, it fetches a record from DS. 
Just today, we noticed that, right before 504s, there had been one occurrence of DS timeout error. Afterwards, the container just carried on and some % of users was getting 504s. So the current theory is that we might need to improve error handling and that Cloud Run may not kill unhealthy containers...

Comment: Can you show how you're initializing the DataStore client with regards to your application?

Comment: We have our own connector class 'DataBase' which stores the reference to DS client in one of its properties, we instantiate it like this `self.client = db.Client()`

We initialise  'DataBase' right before we launch Flask application and store the instance in global app config. Worth noting, there is only one instance of this connection object. 

app.py:
`app.app.config['DATABASE'] = DataBase(project=project)` and then `app.run(...)`

Comment: Dustin: Did cherry9090 give you the information you need?

Comment: Can you relate about 504 response with the following error from your Stackdriver logs? Maybe the answer lies in there.

Comment: We found it was caused by Datastore hanging. It occasionally would take somewhere between 30 mins to 2 hours in order for DS response to come back. During this time the entire web server thread would be blocked and all requests forwarded to that thread would get a 504.